# Remove space from bash cat output in python 2.7

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running this command in python2.7

```
batch_id_number = subprocess.check_output(["cat BATCH_ID.txt"], shell=True)
print (batch_id_number + "hello")
```

I want to store the output of cat command into the variable **batch_id_number**

When I run the program I get the id but with an extra line like this:

```
$ python test.py 
777
hello
```

Instead of:

```
$ python test.py 
777hello
```

If I cat the file I get the ID withot extra lines:

```
$ cat BATCH_ID.txt 
777
```

Comment: When you're using `shell=True`, the first argument should be a string, not a list.

Comment: @Barmar could you help me with the right command please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `rstrip()` to remove trailing newlines from a string.

```
print(batch_id_number.rstrip('\n') + "hello")
```

Comment: You can omit arguments, `rstrip()` will remove all whitespaces by default.

Comment: Maybe they don't want all whitespace removed.